# How to capture one particular instance of a string only if it occurs twice in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression:

```
/diff\\left\((...*?\\right\){0,1})\\right\)/gm
```

and the string I want to match is
`diff\left(5x^2\right) + diff\left(5x^2+\tan\left(x\right)\right)`

I want to match in such a way that there are two matches:
`diff\left(5x^2+\right)` and `diff\left(5x^2+\tan\left(x\right)\right)`
each having captured groups `5x^2` and `5x^2+\tan\left(x\right)`.

I want to add `\right)` inside a captured group once only if it occurs twice.

However, I'm only getting a single match with the entire `5x^2\right)+diff\left(5x^2+\tan\left(x\right)` inside a captured group.

Here are two images for better understanding. Blue parts represent matches and green parts represent captured groups

Here is the output I'm getting (screenshot from regex101)
[image]

Desired output (this is an edited image)
[image]

Please help me with this I'm trying to build a symbolic calculator app. Thanks

Comment: You'd use the global parameters and match for your search, the output would have 2 or more duplicate finds and you can run your code to accept/decline in such case. "g" and if necessary for multi-line "m" so gm is fine, you may want gmi for case-insensitivity.

Comment: Please fix your formatting as it is very hard to read at the moment. This will help people answer your question.

Comment: How does an image of the output **TEXT** or the desired **TEXT** help us help you? Also, Regex101 has a save option that gives you a link to share with others.

Answer (score 1):

If those two parts are to always be bound by `space` characters, you could try something like the below:
https://regex101.com/r/Lcsxxv/1

[image: regex101.com snip]

```js
const regex = /diff\\left\(([^ ]*)\\right\)/gm;
const str   = `diff\\left(5x^2\\right) + diff\\left(5x^2+\\tan\\left(x\\right)\\right)`;

const matches = [];
const groups  = [];

let r;
while ((r = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(r[0]);
  groups.push(r[1]);
}

console.log(`matches:\n\t${matches.join('\n\t')}
groups:\n\t${groups.join('\n\t')}`)
```

The way it works is that it's going to look for the *last* instance of `\right)` until either the end of the string or a `space` character, whichever comes first.

I hope this answers your question.